# Save variables into a struct from the workspace

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I have three variables, two are named  `number_of_steps_...` and the third one is `struct`.

How can I save the content saved in the `number_of_steps` variables into `struct`?

I have tried the `save` command but that doesn't work for what I need. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "save", but you can add them to the struct by using

```
mystruct.number_of_steps1 = number_of_steps1
mystruct.number_of_steps2 = number_of_steps2
```

Then save the struct to a file using

```
save mystruct.mat mystruct
```

Notice I've taken the liberty of renaming the variable `struct` as `mystruct`. Since ["struct" is a Matlab command](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), it's not a good idea to use it as a variable name.

Comment: I need to get the data from variables NUMBER_OF_STEPS1 and NUMBER_OF_STEPS2 and save it insiade the STRUCT/MYSTRUCT

Comment: You mean "save" as in they are stored within the struct variable, or as in saved as a file on your computer? Have you tried the above lines of code? Use backticks (`, next to the 1 on your keyboard) to format stuff as code, instead of needing all caps...

Comment: I have in workspace structural variable 'struct' which contains nine other variables and I want to get 'number_of_steps_left_foot' and 'number_of_steps_right_foot' to the 'struct' ..so after 'struct' will contain 9 variables + 'number_of_steps_left_foot' and 'number_of_steps_right_foot'

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!